# Break On Debug.WriteLine

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

Can I get Visual Studio to break on any Debug.WriteLine?

I have a Debug.WriteLine that is just writing a number and I cannot find it to turn it off.

I have it down to one method call but even holding F11 for 20 minutes did not get to the mutant Debug.WriteLine

Comment: Step into? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Use the Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function.  Enter "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine" for the function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function.  Enter "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine" for the function name.  That sets 5 breakpoints, one for each overload.

Do consider that it might not be generated by managed code, the default trace listener that normally displays Debug.WriteLine() output uses a debugger function (OutputDebugString) to produce output.  That function may also be used by native code.

Comment: Thanks - that found it.  Now how do I delete THAT BreakPoint?   If I have to delete all then cool - but would like to keep my manual BreakPoints.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Breakpoints to manage your breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks again.   You are 541K for a reason.   Now I have a delay with symbols loading that I never had before.  But I can open another question.